# How to detect Intel SSD that freeze on boot on Thinkpad T450?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, thinkpad

Few days ago, after starting my laptop, all i saw was frozen `To interrupt normal startup, press Enter` screen. No response to the keys, only few times after 3-5 mins i got also `Error 2100: HDD0 (Hard disk drive) initialization error (1)`

Inside i got Intel SSD SSD0E97920, working like a charm for few years without any problems. After putting in another SSD, Thinkpad boots fine.

When checking Intel SSD on another laptop bios did not detected it, but it was an over decade old Dell that i took replacement SSD from... So i checked malfunctioning Intel SSD on external Unitek bridge and after plugin in GParted is stuck on `Confirming /dev/sdb`, same when i try to `fdisk -l`, term gets stuck and unresponsive to ctrl+c.

Did someone had similar problem or have some idea if something still can be done here? I just want to know if there is still some hope to rescue it or is it hammer time.

Comment: SSDs fail, *any device* at some point fails, after "working fine for years". What is your question?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen thanks for answer, question is if there is an option to detect it and recover any stuff from it?

Comment: I advice you to edit your question to make the *question* [more clear](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). In it's current form there's good chance it will be closed.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen corrected, thanks :)

Comment: There are posts regarding recovering data, including from SSD drives. It's usually worth trying to recover data, but it is always true that backups are better.